# Json transformation and problem with null values management in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json string and I want to do some changes to it with the following code in Java using Jackson:

```
public String transformJson(String json) {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Student s = mapper.readValue(json, Student.class))

    // Do some changes on the object s

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(s);
}
```

Here is the Student class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public static class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String country;
    private Long age;
}
```

The code above works and let's suppose the json in input is the following:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Jim",
   "lastName" : "Miles"
}
```

If no change is done, the output would be the same. The annotation @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) would just remove any null field from the output.

But now the new requirement is this: when the input json explicity define a value as null, then the output should show that field as null. That means that when the input is the following:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Jim",
   "lastName" : "Miles",
   "country" : null 
}
```

Then the output should still be:

```
{
   "firstName" : "Jim",
   "lastName" : "Miles",
   "country" : null 
}
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You could try wrapping all your fields in `AtomicReference`, but that's not really elegant. What's the point in having the property with value null? What's the difference between `{country: null}` and `{}`?

Comment: When you need to transform JSON->JSON, sometimes you may find useful to don't use an intermediate object representation at all. See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791