# Require help in json manipulations using java

Tags: java, json, api

Can anyone from java background/api automation background  can help me with below manipulations.

if possible share piece of code in comments

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name": "sonoo",   
        "salary": 56000,   
        "married": true  
        "fab": false
        "id": 22
        "key1": null
        "key2": null
        "key3": "sam"
        "DateTime": 2016-12-21 00:00:00.000
    }  
}
```

1.How can i Replace the `null` value with `" "`

2.How can i replace `DateTime` to `2016-12-21` wherever it is present , if it present at mutiple loactions then i have to manipulate all `dateTime` to desired date

3.How can i replace all the boolean ( `true`/`false`) to (`0`/`1`)

Scenario : I have to compare actual and expected json, before doing that i have to manipulate the above conditions

Appreciate your quick inputs

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Do you have any preferable Java library for JSON manipulation?

Comment: See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791 This is a technique when you read a json in stream/event/token oriented manner and produce result json on-the-fly with required modifications (filtering/updating/etc). This the most efficient (in both CPU/memory usage) and flexible technique.