# How to replace a value of the given key path in dynamic json object using java

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have dynamic JSONs and their key-path,
I need to change the values of the Json on received key paths

As an example, in have below JSON and key (cars.car1)

```html
{
   "name":"John",
   "age":null,
   "time":"2021",
   "vType":"yes",
   "cars":{
      "car1":"Ford",
      "car2":"BMW",
      "car3":"Fiat"
   },
   "lastOverScore":[
      4,
      1,
      6,
      6,
      2,
      1
   ],
   "letterSet":[
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d"
   ]
}
```

I need to change the value of **cars.car1.** as "Benz".
**Also Please Note**
JSON body and its keys will change from time to time.

As an example, next time I may get a totally different JSON body with related key.

The key for the below JSON is: errors.source.pointer
(Need to change the value of the given key)

```html
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "source": { "pointer": "test" },
      "detail":  "Missing `data` Member at document's top level."
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea to do this with Java

Comment: You could try to look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422516/how-to-update-json-value-using-java/64424791#64424791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through below code able to replace or remove the given item.

```
public JSONObject updateOrRemoveJsonProperty(Object js1, String keys, Object valueNew, ConfigData.JsonBuildType payloadEnum, String targetKey){
   try {
       List<String> keyMain = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(keys.split("\\.")));

       for (int i = 0; i < keyMain.size(); i++) {
           if(js1 instanceof JSONObject || js1 instanceof JSONArray){
               if(keyMain.size() >1 && i+1 < keyMain.size()) {
                   String tmpKey= "";
                   String stringArray ="";
                   try {
                       tmpKey = keyMain.get(i);
                       keyMain.remove(i);
                       stringArray = StringUtils.join(keyMain, ".");
                       keyMain.clear();
                       updateOrRemoveJsonProperty(((JSONObject) js1).get(tmpKey), stringArray, valueNew, payloadEnum, targetKey);
                   }catch (JSONException js){
                       if(!tmpKey.isEmpty() && tmpKey.matches(KeyMapper.KEYLSTREGX)){
                           String[] tmp = tmpKey.replaceFirst(KeyMapper.KEYLSTREGX, "$1, $2").split(",");
                           try {
                               updateOrRemoveJsonProperty((JSONArray)(((JSONArray)((JSONObject) js1).get(tmp[0])).get(Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim()))), stringArray, valueNew, payloadEnum, targetKey);
                           }catch (ClassCastException ex){
                               updateOrRemoveJsonProperty((JSONObject)(((JSONArray)((JSONObject) js1).get(tmp[0])).get(Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim()))), stringArray, valueNew, payloadEnum, targetKey);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               } else {
                   if((keyMain.get(i)).length() > 2 && keyMain.get(i).matches(KeyMapper.KEYLSTREGX)){
                       String[] tmp = keyMain.get(i).replaceFirst(KeyMapper.KEYLSTREGX, "$1, $2").split(",");
                       if(targetKey != "" && tmp[0].trim().equals(targetKey) && !payloadEnum.equals(ConfigData.JsonBuildType.REMOVE)) {
                           ((JSONObject) js1).put(tmp[0], valueNew);
                       } else if (targetKey != "" && tmp[0].trim().equals(targetKey) && payloadEnum.equals(ConfigData.JsonBuildType.REMOVE)){
                           ((JSONObject) js1).remove(tmp[0]);
                       }

                   }
                   if(targetKey != "" && keyMain.get(i).equals(targetKey) && !payloadEnum.equals(ConfigData.JsonBuildType.REMOVE)) {
                       ((JSONObject) js1).put(keyMain.get(i), valueNew);
                   } else if (targetKey != "" && keyMain.get(i).equals(targetKey) && payloadEnum.equals(ConfigData.JsonBuildType.REMOVE)){
                       ((JSONObject) js1).remove(keyMain.get(i));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }catch (JSONException  ex){

   }

    return (JSONObject) js1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either deserialise to `Map<String, Object>` (where the object can be another similar map), reach in to the structure, make your change, the serialise to json,
or...

```
json = json.replaceAll("(?s)(\"cars":.*?\"car1":").*?\"", "$1" + newValue + "\"");
```

Comment: Can you please explain how do it through 'Map<String, Object> ' and return the modified object. I cannot use replace all due to key-path variations. I can do the Json iterations as per the length of the keys, But no idea how to do it through iteration